# push() function override last item in array

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have two objects:

```
ej= {
    name="",
    code: "",
    namebusinessG:"",
    codebusinessG:""
};  
group = {
    name:"",
    code:""
}
```

And two arrays that will contain these objects

```
groupList:any[]=[];
ejList:any[]=[];
```

My program should work like this :

- When add a group to groupList : Test if group exist in groupList, if not add it
- When add a ej to ejList : Test **if ej exist** in ejList, **if not exist**, add it. Then  the program should add ej.codebusinessG and ej.namebusinessG to groupList, but it should verify **before** if ej.codebusinessG exist already in the list of groupList.code, if not, then add it.

  ```
  selectItem(event) {
      if (!this.toggle) { // in group
          if (this.groupList.length == 0) {
              this.groupList.push(event);
          } else if (this.testNotExistinginArray(event, this.groupList)) {
              this.groupList.push(event);
          }

      } else { //in ej
          if (this.ejList.length == 0) {
              this.ejList.push(event);
              if (this.groupList.length == 0) {
                  this.groupList.push({
                      code: event.codebusinessG,
                      name: event.nameBusinessG
                  });
              }
          } else if (this.testNotExistinginArray(event, this.ejList)) {

              this.ejList.push(event);

              this.group.code = event.codeBusinessG;
              this.group.name = event.nameBusinessG;
              if (this.testNotExistinginArray(this.group, this.groupList)) {
                  this.groupList.push(this.group);

              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Here's the function that test if code is in array or not:

```
testNotExistinginArray(event,type) {

    let notExist=true;
            type.forEach (function(elm) {
                if(elm.code === event.code) {
                    notExist=false
                }
            })
    return notExist;
}
```

**Actual behaviour**

When I add Group : verificiation + add **OK**

When I add ej: verificiation + add **OK**

But After adding ej for the first and second time , the group corresponding group is added correcty.

But When I add a third ej , the ej is added to list but the corresponding group overwride the last item in groupList.

Here's more details

When I add a first ej. (the ej and group are added)

[image]

When I add a second  ( ej and group added )

[image]

then I the third

[image]

the codebusinessG is overriding the last group in groupList instead of add after it.

**Expected behavior**

when Add an `ej` add the ej.codebusinessG + ej.namebusinessG after the last Item in groupList.

For information I'm using angular 5 and Primeng [autocomplete component](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/autocomplete) :

```
 <p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="text" [suggestions]="results" (completeMethod)="search($event)"
 emptyMessage={{noBorrowerResult}} 
 [minLength]="3"

 placeholder="Exemple: Apple"
 [size] = "40"
 field = "name"
 [multiple]="true"
 >
 <ng-template let-elm pTemplate="item">
    <div class="suggestion-item">{{elm.name}} ( ID: {{elm.code}} )</div>
 </ng-template>
 </p-autoComplete>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have simplified your code and provided you an example with **[this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7fsudc?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts)**.

```
addUniqueObjectToArray(obj, array, criteria, criteriaTwo?) {
  if (array.some(g => g[criteria] === obj[criteriaTwo ? criteriaTwo : criteria])) { return; }
  array.push(obj);
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.addUniqueObjectToArray(this.newGroup, this.groupList, 'code');
  this.addUniqueObjectToArray(this.newGroup, this.groupList, 'code');

  this.addUniqueObjectToArray(this.ej, this.ejList, 'code');
  this.addUniqueObjectToArray(this.ej, this.ejList, 'code');
  this.addUniqueObjectToArray(this.ej, this.groupList, 'code', 'codebusinessG');
  this.addUniqueObjectToArray(this.ej, this.groupList, 'code', 'codebusinessG');

  console.log('Groups : ', this.groupList, ' EJs : ', this.ejList);

}
```

You now have a do-it-all function that compares two keys, and push in the array only if the array doesn't contain this key.

If you pass only one key, it will compare on this key, otherwise you can pass another key to change the compare function. Feel free to try it in the stackblitz, it's made for that.

**EDIT** To avoid reference issues :

```
this.addUniqueObjectToArray({code: 'CODE'}, this.ejList, 'code');
const newObj = {code: 'CODE'};
this.addUniqueObjectToArray(newObj, this.ejList, 'code');
```

Give a new object to the function, not one that is already created.

Comment: As for your overwriting issue, I recommend you to stop pushing in the same object. Instead, create an object everytime, then push it. Objects are referenced into arrays, this means that if you change an object property, the change will be propagated to both arrays.

Comment: Can you provide me an example the explain your comment ?

Comment: It  works,  thanks a lot!I it was a reference problem, I have created new object then push them every time ==> no override problem

Comment: Glad I could help !